# Correcting coc.nvim colours

Tags: neovim

I'm currently customizing my neovim using packer and I ran to a package for code auto completion known as coc.nvim. The current colour scheme that I am using is a custom one with dark grey background with white, yellow and green font.

They are 2 things that I would like to change about the looks and aren't matching with my colour scheme.

1. Before line numbers there's a little light grey block that turns to a red `>>` on errors. I would like to change the colour from light grey to dark grey.
2. Most stuff from the completion menu are blue, such as markers for how much of an option I have typed & line breaks at documentations. I would like to change those to yellow.

[image]

Comment: Maybe could you post a screenshot to give us more indication about the sign for which you would like to have a different color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coc introduce a number of highlight group to configure the color of the sign it introduce:

```
CocWarningHighlight xxx cterm=underline ctermfg=3 gui=undercurl guifg=#EBCB8B
CocErrorHighlight xxx cterm=underline ctermfg=1 gui=undercurl guifg=#BF616A
CocWarningSign xxx ctermfg=3 guifg=#d08770
CocErrorSign   xxx ctermfg=1 guifg=#bf616a
CocInfoSign    xxx ctermfg=6 guifg=#88C0D0
CocHintSign    xxx ctermfg=12 guifg=#5E81AC
CocHighlightText xxx guifg=#d8dee9 guibg=#516f7a
CocFadeOut     xxx links to Comment
CocErrorVirtualText xxx guifg=#bf616a
CocWarningVirtualText xxx guifg=#d08770
CocMenuSel     xxx ctermbg=8 guibg=#4C566A
CocListLine    xxx ctermbg=17 guibg=#3e434e
CocTreeSelected xxx links to CursorLine
CocSelectedText xxx ctermfg=12 guifg=#fb4934
CocCodeLens    xxx ctermfg=7 guifg=#999999
CocUnderline   xxx term=underline cterm=underline gui=underline guisp=#ebdbb2
CocBold        xxx term=bold cterm=bold gui=bold
CocItalic      xxx term=italic cterm=italic gui=italic
CocStrikeThrough xxx term=strikethrough cterm=strikethrough gui=strikethrough
CocMarkdownLink xxx ctermfg=9 guifg=#15aabf
CocDisabled    xxx ctermfg=7 guifg=#999999
CocSearch      xxx ctermfg=9 guifg=#15aabf
CocLink        xxx term=underline cterm=underline gui=underline guisp=#15aabf
CocFloating    xxx links to Pmenu
CocFloatThumb  xxx links to PmenuThumb
CocFloatSbar   xxx links to PmenuSbar
CocFloatActive xxx links to CocSearch
CocMarkdownCode xxx links to markdownCode
CocMarkdownHeader xxx links to markdownH1
CocDeprecatedHighlight xxx links to CocStrikeThrough
CocUnusedHighlight xxx links to CocFadeOut
CocListSearch  xxx links to CocSearch
CocListMode    xxx links to ModeMsg
CocListPath    xxx links to Comment
CocHoverRange  xxx links to Search
CocCursorRange xxx links to Search
CocLinkedEditing xxx links to CocCursorRange
CocHighlightRead xxx links to CocHighlightText
CocHighlightWrite xxx links to CocHighlightText
CocNotificationProgress xxx ctermfg=9 guifg=#15aabf
CocNotificationButton xxx links to CocUnderline
CocNotificationError xxx links to CocErrorFloat
CocErrorFloat  xxx ctermfg=1 ctermbg=0 guifg=#bf616a guibg=#434C5E
CocNotificationWarning xxx links to CocWarningFloat
CocWarningFloat xxx ctermfg=3 ctermbg=0 guifg=#d08770 guibg=#434C5E
CocNotificationInfo xxx links to CocInfoFloat
CocInfoFloat   xxx ctermfg=6 ctermbg=0 guifg=#88C0D0 guibg=#434C5E
CocSnippetVisual xxx links to Visual
CocTreeTitle   xxx links to Title
CocTreeDescription xxx links to Comment
CocTreeOpenClose xxx links to CocBold
CocSelectedRange xxx links to CocHighlightText
CocSymbolDefault xxx links to MoreMsg
CocPumSearch   xxx links to CocSearch
CocPumDetail   xxx links to Comment
CocPumMenu     xxx links to CocFloating
CocPumShortcut xxx links to Comment
CocPumDeprecated xxx links to CocStrikeThrough
CocVirtualText xxx ctermfg=12 guifg=#504945
CocPumVirtualText xxx links to CocVirtualText
CocInputBoxVirtualText xxx links to CocVirtualText
CocFloatDividingLine xxx links to CocVirtualText
CocInfoHighlight xxx links to CocUnderline
CocInfoVirtualText xxx ctermfg=6 ctermbg=16 guifg=#88C0D0 guibg=#2E3440
CocHintHighlight xxx links to CocUnderline
CocHintVirtualText xxx ctermfg=12 ctermbg=16 guifg=#5E81AC guibg=#2E3440
CocHintFloat   xxx ctermfg=12 ctermbg=0 guifg=#5E81AC guibg=#434C5E
CocInlayHint   xxx ctermfg=12 ctermbg=16 guifg=#5E81AC guibg=#2E3440
CocInlayHintParameter xxx links to CocInlayHint
CocInlayHintType xxx links to CocInlayHint
CocListBlackBlack xxx guifg=#3B4252 guibg=#3B4252
CocListBlackBlue xxx guifg=#3B4252 guibg=#81A1C1
CocListBlackGreen xxx guifg=#3B4252 guibg=#A3BE8C
CocListBlackGrey xxx guifg=#3B4252 guibg=#4C566A
CocListBlackWhite xxx guifg=#3B4252 guibg=#E5E9F0
CocListBlackCyan xxx guifg=#3B4252 guibg=#88C0D0
CocListBlackYellow xxx guifg=#3B4252 guibg=#EBCB8B
CocListBlackMagenta xxx guifg=#3B4252 guibg=#B48EAD
CocListBlackRed xxx guifg=#3B4252 guibg=#BF616A
CocListFgBlack xxx ctermfg=0 guifg=#3B4252
CocListBgBlack xxx ctermbg=0 guibg=#3B4252
CocListBlueBlack xxx guifg=#81A1C1 guibg=#3B4252
CocListBlueBlue xxx guifg=#81A1C1 guibg=#81A1C1
CocListBlueGreen xxx guifg=#81A1C1 guibg=#A3BE8C
CocListBlueGrey xxx guifg=#81A1C1 guibg=#4C566A
CocListBlueWhite xxx guifg=#81A1C1 guibg=#E5E9F0
CocListBlueCyan xxx guifg=#81A1C1 guibg=#88C0D0
CocListBlueYellow xxx guifg=#81A1C1 guibg=#EBCB8B
CocListBlueMagenta xxx guifg=#81A1C1 guibg=#B48EAD
CocListBlueRed xxx guifg=#81A1C1 guibg=#BF616A
CocListFgBlue  xxx ctermfg=9 guifg=#81A1C1
CocListBgBlue  xxx ctermbg=9 guibg=#81A1C1
CocListGreenBlack xxx guifg=#A3BE8C guibg=#3B4252
CocListGreenBlue xxx guifg=#A3BE8C guibg=#81A1C1
CocListGreenGreen xxx guifg=#A3BE8C guibg=#A3BE8C
CocListGreenGrey xxx guifg=#A3BE8C guibg=#4C566A
CocListGreenWhite xxx guifg=#A3BE8C guibg=#E5E9F0
CocListGreenCyan xxx guifg=#A3BE8C guibg=#88C0D0
CocListGreenYellow xxx guifg=#A3BE8C guibg=#EBCB8B
CocListGreenMagenta xxx guifg=#A3BE8C guibg=#B48EAD
CocListGreenRed xxx guifg=#A3BE8C guibg=#BF616A
CocListFgGreen xxx ctermfg=10 guifg=#A3BE8C
CocListBgGreen xxx ctermbg=10 guibg=#A3BE8C
CocListGreyBlack xxx guifg=#4C566A guibg=#3B4252
CocListGreyBlue xxx guifg=#4C566A guibg=#81A1C1
CocListGreyGreen xxx guifg=#4C566A guibg=#A3BE8C
CocListGreyGrey xxx guifg=#4C566A guibg=#4C566A
CocListGreyWhite xxx guifg=#4C566A guibg=#E5E9F0
CocListGreyCyan xxx guifg=#4C566A guibg=#88C0D0
CocListGreyYellow xxx guifg=#4C566A guibg=#EBCB8B
CocListGreyMagenta xxx guifg=#4C566A guibg=#B48EAD
CocListGreyRed xxx guifg=#4C566A guibg=#BF616A
CocListFgGrey  xxx ctermfg=7 guifg=#4C566A
CocListBgGrey  xxx ctermbg=7 guibg=#4C566A
CocListWhiteBlack xxx guifg=#E5E9F0 guibg=#3B4252
CocListWhiteBlue xxx guifg=#E5E9F0 guibg=#81A1C1
CocListWhiteGreen xxx guifg=#E5E9F0 guibg=#A3BE8C
CocListWhiteGrey xxx guifg=#E5E9F0 guibg=#4C566A
CocListWhiteWhite xxx guifg=#E5E9F0 guibg=#E5E9F0
CocListWhiteCyan xxx guifg=#E5E9F0 guibg=#88C0D0
CocListWhiteYellow xxx guifg=#E5E9F0 guibg=#EBCB8B
CocListWhiteMagenta xxx guifg=#E5E9F0 guibg=#B48EAD
CocListWhiteRed xxx guifg=#E5E9F0 guibg=#BF616A
CocListFgWhite xxx ctermfg=15 guifg=#E5E9F0
CocListBgWhite xxx ctermbg=15 guibg=#E5E9F0
CocListCyanBlack xxx guifg=#88C0D0 guibg=#3B4252
CocListCyanBlue xxx guifg=#88C0D0 guibg=#81A1C1
CocListCyanGreen xxx guifg=#88C0D0 guibg=#A3BE8C
CocListCyanGrey xxx guifg=#88C0D0 guibg=#4C566A
CocListCyanWhite xxx guifg=#88C0D0 guibg=#E5E9F0
CocListCyanCyan xxx guifg=#88C0D0 guibg=#88C0D0
CocListCyanYellow xxx guifg=#88C0D0 guibg=#EBCB8B
CocListCyanMagenta xxx guifg=#88C0D0 guibg=#B48EAD
CocListCyanRed xxx guifg=#88C0D0 guibg=#BF616A
CocListFgCyan  xxx ctermfg=11 guifg=#88C0D0
CocListBgCyan  xxx ctermbg=11 guibg=#88C0D0
CocListYellowBlack xxx guifg=#EBCB8B guibg=#3B4252
CocListYellowBlue xxx guifg=#EBCB8B guibg=#81A1C1
CocListYellowGreen xxx guifg=#EBCB8B guibg=#A3BE8C
CocListYellowGrey xxx guifg=#EBCB8B guibg=#4C566A
CocListYellowWhite xxx guifg=#EBCB8B guibg=#E5E9F0
CocListYellowCyan xxx guifg=#EBCB8B guibg=#88C0D0
CocListYellowYellow xxx guifg=#EBCB8B guibg=#EBCB8B
CocListYellowMagenta xxx guifg=#EBCB8B guibg=#B48EAD
CocListYellowRed xxx guifg=#EBCB8B guibg=#BF616A
CocListFgYellow xxx ctermfg=14 guifg=#EBCB8B
CocListBgYellow xxx ctermbg=14 guibg=#EBCB8B
CocListMagentaBlack xxx guifg=#B48EAD guibg=#3B4252
CocListMagentaBlue xxx guifg=#B48EAD guibg=#81A1C1
CocListMagentaGreen xxx guifg=#B48EAD guibg=#A3BE8C
CocListMagentaGrey xxx guifg=#B48EAD guibg=#4C566A
CocListMagentaWhite xxx guifg=#B48EAD guibg=#E5E9F0
CocListMagentaCyan xxx guifg=#B48EAD guibg=#88C0D0
CocListMagentaYellow xxx guifg=#B48EAD guibg=#EBCB8B
CocListMagentaMagenta xxx guifg=#B48EAD guibg=#B48EAD
CocListMagentaRed xxx guifg=#B48EAD guibg=#BF616A
CocListFgMagenta xxx ctermfg=13 guifg=#B48EAD
CocListBgMagenta xxx ctermbg=13 guibg=#B48EAD
CocListRedBlack xxx guifg=#BF616A guibg=#3B4252
CocListRedBlue xxx guifg=#BF616A guibg=#81A1C1
CocListRedGreen xxx guifg=#BF616A guibg=#A3BE8C
CocListRedGrey xxx guifg=#BF616A guibg=#4C566A
CocListRedWhite xxx guifg=#BF616A guibg=#E5E9F0
CocListRedCyan xxx guifg=#BF616A guibg=#88C0D0
CocListRedYellow xxx guifg=#BF616A guibg=#EBCB8B
CocListRedMagenta xxx guifg=#BF616A guibg=#B48EAD
CocListRedRed  xxx guifg=#BF616A guibg=#BF616A
CocListFgRed   xxx ctermfg=12 guifg=#BF616A
CocListBgRed   xxx ctermbg=12 guibg=#BF616A
CocSemNumber   xxx links to Number
CocSemFunction xxx links to Function
CocSemKeyword  xxx links to Keyword
CocSemParameter xxx links to Identifier
CocSemEvent    xxx links to Keyword
CocSemModifier xxx links to StorageClass
CocSemMacro    xxx links to Define
CocSemDeprecated xxx links to CocDeprecatedHighlight
CocSemClass    xxx links to Special
CocSemDecorator xxx links to Identifier
CocSemOperator xxx links to Operator
CocSemStruct   xxx links to Identifier
CocSemRegexp   xxx links to String
CocSemMethod   xxx links to Function
CocSemComment  xxx links to Comment
CocSemEnum     xxx links to Type
CocSemInterface xxx links to Type
CocSemType     xxx links to Type
CocSemProperty xxx links to Identifier
CocSemTypeParameter xxx links to Identifier
CocSemEnumMember xxx links to Constant
CocSemBoolean  xxx links to Boolean
CocSemNamespace xxx links to Include
CocSemString   xxx links to String
CocSemVariable xxx links to Identifier
CocSymbolUnit  xxx ctermfg=6 guifg=#88C0D0
CocSymbolNumber xxx ctermfg=5 guifg=#B48EAD
CocSymbolFunction xxx ctermfg=6 guifg=#88C0D0
CocSymbolKey   xxx ctermfg=223 guifg=#D8DEE9
CocSymbolKeyword xxx ctermfg=4 guifg=#81A1C1
CocSymbolReference xxx ctermfg=223 guifg=#D8DEE9
CocSymbolFolder xxx ctermfg=6 guifg=#88C0D0
CocSymbolVariable xxx ctermfg=223 guifg=#D8DEE9
CocSymbolNull  xxx ctermfg=4 guifg=#81A1C1
CocSymbolValue xxx ctermfg=6 guifg=#88C0D0
CocSymbolConstant xxx ctermfg=223 guifg=#D8DEE9
CocSymbolText  xxx ctermfg=6 guifg=#88C0D0
CocSymbolModule xxx ctermfg=4 guifg=#81A1C1
CocSymbolPackage xxx ctermfg=4 guifg=#81A1C1
CocSymbolClass xxx ctermfg=223 guifg=#D8DEE9
CocSymbolOperator xxx ctermfg=4 guifg=#81A1C1
CocSymbolStruct xxx ctermfg=4 guifg=#81A1C1
CocSymbolObject xxx ctermfg=6 guifg=#88C0D0
CocSymbolMethod xxx ctermfg=6 guifg=#88C0D0
CocSymbolArray xxx ctermfg=6 guifg=#88C0D0
CocSymbolEnum  xxx ctermfg=6 guifg=#88C0D0
CocSymbolField xxx ctermfg=223 guifg=#D8DEE9
CocSymbolInterface xxx ctermfg=6 guifg=#88C0D0
CocSymbolProperty xxx ctermfg=223 guifg=#D8DEE9
CocSymbolColor xxx ctermfg=5 guifg=#B48EAD
CocSymbolFile  xxx ctermfg=4 guifg=#81A1C1
CocSymbolEvent xxx ctermfg=223 guifg=#D8DEE9
CocSymbolTypeParameter xxx ctermfg=223 guifg=#D8DEE9
CocSymbolConstructor xxx ctermfg=223 guifg=#D8DEE9
CocSymbolSnippet xxx ctermfg=6 guifg=#88C0D0
CocSymbolBoolean xxx ctermfg=4 guifg=#81A1C1
CocSymbolNamespace xxx ctermfg=4 guifg=#81A1C1
CocSymbolString xxx ctermfg=2 guifg=#A3BE8C
CocSymbolEnumMember xxx ctermfg=223 guifg=#D8DEE9
CocSelectedLine xxx cleared
CocErrorLine   xxx cleared
CocWarningLine xxx cleared
CocInfoLine    xxx cleared
CocHintLine    xxx cleared
```

I suspect the ones you want to modify for the first problem are:

```
CocWarningSign
CocErrorSign
CocInfoSign
CocHintSign

SignColumn
```

The ones you want to modify for the second are probably:

```
CocFloating
CocSearch
```

Comment: Thanks the first problem is now solved, but not the second one. `CocFloating` changes the colour of suggestions, which is white & it is fine. I'm talking about the colour that highlights how much of the suggestion you have already typed. For example when typing `co` a suggestion will pop up with `cout` text, highlighting the `co` part with blue

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Could you provide a screenshot? It would ease the understanding :-)

Comment: I just added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Thanks I suppose then `CocSearch` is the group you are searching for.